# Agora Console - App has Key icon greyed out - Cannot generate a temp token

Tags: agora.io

I have created my first app and it is in the Test stage. In the Console, Project Managment I can see a row for the project. Under the Functions column, I can click the Demo link, but the key icon adjacent to the demo link, where I believe I can create a temporary token, is disabled. Any ideas how I can enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might caused by you creating a wrong type of project. When you click "create" to create a new project in Project Management, remember to select "APP ID + APP Certificate + Token". You probably selected "APP ID" option by accident.

[image]

Only if you choose the first one, you will see the key icon enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to move to the App ID + App Certificate + Token option, this then allows a test token to be created.